# Jupyter Scala notebook not recognizing Scala anonymous function using Java List

Tags: java, scala, jupyter-notebook, anonymous-function

I think I have something misconfigured in my Jupyter / Scala setup, but I'm having a lot of trouble diagnosing the issue.
Here's the code I'm trying to run, via a fresh docker image (beakerx/beakerx) and a fresh kernel:

```
import java.util.Arrays
var original = Arrays.asList("hello", "world", "war")
original.stream().map(_.toUpperCase()).forEach(wat => println(wat))
```

This works fine through the REPL, but when I run through Jupyter, I get this error:

```
<console>:91: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.toUpperCase())
   original.stream().map(_.toUpperCase()).forEach(wat => println(wat))
```

I also tried replacing `_.toUpperCase()` with `n => n.toUpperCase()`, but got the same error. Using `(n:String) => n.toUpperCase()` gives a related error:

```
<console>:92: error: type mismatch;
found   : String => String
required: java.util.function.Function[_ >: String, _]
   original.stream().map((n:String) => n.toUpperCase()).forEach(wat => println(wat))
```

Skipping the Stream also fails:

```
java.util.Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c").map(_.toUpperCase())
```

yields

```
<console>:89: error: value map is not a member of java.util.List[String]
   java.util.Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c").map(_.toUpperCase())
```

Here's the "current kernel information" from the Help tab:

```
BeakerX 1.0.0
Scala 2.11.12
hash 99cb191
build time 2018-07-05 19:22 UTC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests: "value map is not a member of java.util.List[String]", you cannot apply map to the java.util.List[String]

You need to convert the java.util.List[String] to a scala collection.

Add this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

Then you can run your code without errors:

```
java.util.Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c").map(_.toUpperCase())
```

Will yield this: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[String] = ArrayBuffer(A, B, C)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are comparing the behavior of Scala 2.12 in the REPL to the behavior of Scala 2.11 in the Jupyter notebook.  Scala 2.12 improved compatibility between Scala functions/lambdas and Java 8's `FunctionalInterface`.  The 2.12 compiler can infer the Scala function type expected by the Java method where the 2.11 compiler cannot.